# Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have been using Stack Overflow to help me solve coding errors (VBA). Now that my code is "completed" (for now), I'm trying to optimize the speed.

Is Stack Overflow the correct place to ask questions of this nature?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No, it isn't the best place - though it is on-topic, there's a better place for such questions:

You can take working code to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) - but do make sure to read their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to see what exactly they expect from a good question.

Comment: The Help Centre doesn't mention that the code can't be working and wouldn't this mean that SO is now solely a "debug this" service? If your code isn't quick enough and you can demonstrate how you're attempting to speed it up I think this counts as a programming problem and SO should be accepting it rather than turning it away.

Comment: @Ben Disagree. The OP's code does work, they just want to optimise it. Code Review is totally the right site for that.

Comment: I'm not disputing that code review is the right site @Chris, merely that SO is not necessarily the wrong one.

Comment: @Ben - requests for "optimize this for me" are not welcome on SO - they are overly open ended. If the OP has a **specific** optimization they would like to ask about, that's different.

Comment: In case there's any doubt; as a moderator on Stack Overflow, this lines up with what we enforce.

Comment: Examples of the types of specific optimization questions that can be appropriate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/295579/327083 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/812512/327083 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/12905426/327083 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/20270596/327083 , etc

Comment: I have a question about how to write efficient code when my application is not yet working, that's OK for SO, but as soon as my application works, I have to take an identical question to Code Review? And what if a module in my application is working, but the rest isn't? Can I ask a question on SO about optimizing that module? It looks to me like the difference has more to do with how much code it is to which you want a response. Questions in SO have to be about constrained problems, not "look over my code" questions. But if it's constrained, why does it matter whether the code already works?

Comment: @Oded What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643675/unexpectedly-slow-cython-convolution-code/)?

Comment: @Veedrac - what about it? Looks very specific, with actual code and notes about what was tried. OP isn't asking for people to review it, but for help with the approach. Frankly, it might fit both sites, but if you have working code and want it reviewed for a specific requirement, code review is a good spot to go to. Some of our sites have overlap, and there isn't always a black and white answer as to "where stuff belongs".

Comment: I don't think questions about code optimization are off topic on Stack Overflow. If you claim otherwise, kindly state your sources. Essentially, Code Review is a sub-set of SO, where you might get better and detailed answers to certain questions. But as far as I can tell, there is nothing in the SO posting policies that would make such a question off-topic.

Comment: I didn't say it was off-topic. I said it isn't the correct place, given that there is a _better_ place for these on Code Review, @Lundin

Answer (score 12):

If the question is "How do I do X programming technique (that happens to make my code faster)", then StackOverflow is the right place.  If it is a more generic "How do I make this better/faster", then CodeReview is the right place (subject to their terms).

Stack Overflow is the place for specific questions about programming.  If it is specific - as in, about a particular function, language element, algorithm, etc., and by that I don't mean "about your specific program" but about a specific element in your program that is 'specific' in the context of programming, not in the context of a program - then it's fine.  If it's "help me do X to my program", then it's probably off topic here, and may or may not be on topic at Code Review.

The fact that you're asking about optimization (or that you're asking about a functioning, production piece of software) isn't relevant directly to the topicality of your question.  Your question should be topical in and of itself, just like homework questions are fine if they're topical ignoring the homework aspect, or regex questions are fine if they're otherwise good questions (really, there is such a thing as a topical regex question!).

However, optimization questions tend to not be good questions, because they tend to be too broad - if the question is "Is there a faster way..." then it's very likely too broad or off topic.  If  the question doesn't have a single, concise answer, it's probably too broad or off topic.  But if you ask "I'm implementing a bubble sort for my vectors, and would like to use a more efficient routine", you might be able to make that on topic and not too broad.

Answer (score 5):

I think if you are specific about what your performance requirements are and how your code is failing to meet those requirements, the question would be fine on Stack Overflow.

If you just want to optimize for the sake of optimization, the answer is likely to be, "premature optimization is the root of all evil".  That might be the answer on Code Review too.