# How can I file a dispute for putting my question as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, closed-questions

I recently asked a **[coding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027575/quicker-way-to-get-a-list-of-the-unique-quarters-within-a-date-range)** that to my opinion satisfies the criteria for a valid question:

- I stated the problem
- I included an example that can be easily replicated (MVP)
- It was not a question seeking debugging help

For some reason however, it got flagged as off-topic by 4 users. After that I have made an attempt to **[edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50027575/revisions)** to make the wording a bit more clear.

The question eventually even received a high quality answer by a **[high quality user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796085/tommaso-belluzzo)**.

Nevertheless, the question is still marked as off-topic, and it has been down-voted once. I am an experienced coder in the associated programming language, and I truly believe that my question has added value for other coders.

I am therefore wondering what I can do for my question to be reviewed again, and if needed to get feedback on what can be done to revise it such that it satisfies the criteria and gets the [CLOSED] label removed?

Comment: I believe a "quicker way" question very often is going to be found to be opinion based and/or too broad. Although it wasn't closed for that reason in this case, apparently.

Comment: I would interpret that as other users not being able to get a repro for this issue.  It is remarkably slow.  Be sure to include version number info.

Comment: @HansPassant Valid point, initially I also asked the question "Efficient" instead of "Quicker". But quicker is to my time also valid because the method that I had proposed in the question takes 16s to complete, whereas the user that answer was able to solve the problem in 0.8s. So in that case it is a speed improvement of the task being fullfilled. And thats exactly what I was looking for, and which I believe is a question that is often valid when programming. How to speed up things? What do you suggest?

Comment: So either too broad, or opinion based, or non-reproducible... It doesn't appear to be a great outlook for the question.

Comment: @yivi 1. It is not opinion based, it is simply improving the time to complete the task. This is a question that is often asked when coding in Matlab as you can do things in multiple ways (e.g. a for loop is generally slow, so people tend to find solutions with using matrices or vectors). 2. Too broad ,I do not see how it can be too broad as I describe a very targetted problem (how to convert string dates to numeric). 3. Non-reproducible is also not valid as the sample code in my question can be directly used to reproduce the problem (and note that there was a very good answer)

Comment: Maybe opinion based is wrong, but there are bound to be multiple implementations that are faster. I think too broad may apply in that sense, since there are too many possible valid answers for this question. And "non-reproducible" because performance questions many times depend a lot on the specifics of your platform, so your results will not necessarily match the results someone else gets. But, I didn't vote or flag your post, nor I am sure this was the case. I'm not arguing this is the case, just saying this could have been the reasoning of the close voters, in case it helps you.

Comment: You did get an answer that you marked as accepted.  Is your desire to have it reopened about getting more (and better) answers, or just because you feel the question doesn't deserve to be closed?

Comment: @psubsee2003 The latter one. I feel that the question doesnt deserve to be closed, such that other users when they find it on the site actually take time to look at the answer and not just assume that it is a weird question not to look at.

Comment: @yivi Ok, I see your reasoning.

Comment: [Also read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: I have exactly the same situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531980/html2canvas-images-cut-off-in-prod-build-angular
I tried to edit my question to make it better, but I'm not entirely sure why it was marked off-topic and closed.
Better feedback would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You edited your question after it was closed, and that will put your question in the reopen review queue.

That was your appeal, and it was rejected: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50027575/timeline (see screenshot below)

Your question may get a second chance of appeal by way of posting this question, but I'm not sure about that. Personally I think it should remain closed, but I think it's borderline.

[image]