# Is a question on how to make this faster in scope

Tags: discussion

If it is working code and the primary interest is making it faster is it in scope on this site.

I typically will answer if I have an answer.  But I answered one recently and one of the comments was working code should go to CodeReview.

I am not finding any specific guidance in the tour or help.

In scope

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software
  development

Comment: Sorry, no, it's off-topic for SO.

Comment: @MartinJames I was kind of hoping for a reference.

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Short answer: If it's a problem specific enough not be closed for being too broad (faster execution time under these types of inputs for example) then it is on topic.

Comment: I agree with the duplicates.  The answer seems to be OK here if it is specific.  There is some short optimization that is off scope scope on CodeReview as they want full working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not finding any specific guidance in the tour or help.

In the same way that we need to exercise judgment when evaluating wether or not an action is "being nice", we need to exercise judgement on wether or not questions are on-topic. All questions in the world will not be listed in a definitive list of what is on-topic or not because that is impossible, so most of the time, there is no "specific guidance" for a situation, we need to extrapolate.

To continue upon anon's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368953/is-a-question-on-how-to-make-this-faster-in-scope#comment596890_368953):

> Short answer: If it's a problem specific enough not be closed for being too broad (faster execution time under these types of inputs for example) then it is on topic.

If there is a way to answer that is not opinion based, that is, it features benchmarks, then yes, by all mean, it is helpful to have actual data when deciding to use this or that algorithm in a given situation.

But these are mostly the exception. Generally, "this is too slow" questions will mostly invite everybody chiming in with their personal experience and very little **actual benchmarks with proof that something is more efficient**. As such, I'd take great care when answering such question, if answering at all.